# Expand image not shown in XPage View in Notes Client (=XPINC)

Tags: xpages, xpinc

In an XPages application opened as XPINC App I have a problem with collapse/expand icons in a categorized view.

For collapse/expand I use own icons (Minus.gif/Plus.gif). The expand icon will shown without any problems, but the collapse icon don't displayed. I can click on it but the image is hidden.

In IE, Chrome, FF and Safari I haven't any problems.

Thanx to all for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions.

1. Where are you images stored?
2. What code are you using the refer to them?

URL references to resources can be different for XPiNC and any server-based resources you're referencing need to be stored on the user's PC if accessing the XPage via XPiNC?

Comment: Hi Paul!

Here my answers:

To 1: The images stored in the Notes database as "Resources\Images"

To 2: I refered them in the "View Column Properties" in Section "Display" for "Expand image" and "Collapse image".

Here the code:

<xp:viewColumn columnName="$14" id="viewColumn1"
  style="width:15px;white-space: nowrap" indentResponses="true"
  expandedImage="/Minus.gif" collapsedImage="/Plus.gif">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="" id="viewColumnHeader1"
            style="width:15px">
 </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>